# Having issues (bugs) with the how the App renders in react

Tags: reactjs, sass, width, parent-child, viewwithtag

The app was created with `npx create-react-app`. The main bug that I am not understanding is that my app renders with white spaces to the sides of the screen. I originally had the files without a specification about the vw or % of the with of the index file and the #root. I am using as well Bootstrap to customize other components.

What I expected was to have a fully sized app rendering the whole screen.

I believe I understand better partially why the navigation bar is not fully using the width of the screen.

My files look like this:

SCSS:

```
$color: #ffc107;
$backgroundcolor: black;
$theme-colors: (
    "outline-warning":#ffc107,
    );

#root {
    background-color: $backgroundcolor;
}

html, head, body{ 
    width: 100%;
}

.movies-couch{
    color: $color;
    background-color: $backgroundcolor;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.main-view{
    color: $color;
    background-color: $backgroundcolor;
    justify-content: center;
}
.search-bar{
    width:80%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.navbar{
    justify-self: center !important;
    
}

.movie-view{
    color: $color;
    background-color: $backgroundcolor;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.movie-card{
    color: $color;
    background-color: $backgroundcolor;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.movie-card-body {
    color: $color;
    background-color: $backgroundcolor;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.login-view, .signup-view{
    color: $backgroundcolor;
    background-color: $color;
    label {
        color:$backgroundcolor;
    }
}

.Navigation-bar{
    color: $color;
    background-color: $backgroundcolor;
    @media (min-width: 375px) {
        margin: 0px -12px;
    }
    @media (min-width:768px) {
        margin: 0px -36px;
    }
    @media (min-width:1024px) {
        margin: 0px -45px;
    }
    @media (min-width:1440px) {
        margin: 0px -73px;
    }
}

.favorite-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    gap: 50px;
    justify-content: space-between;

    @media (max-width: 766px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1440px) {
        gap: 69px;
    }
}


.link_to{
    color: $backgroundcolor;
}


// Importing React Bootstrap utility classes
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Component main-view (where the navigation-bar component will render)

```
...return ( 
<BrowserRouter>
    <NavigationBar user={user} onLoggedOut={onLoggedOut}
         />
        <Row  className="main-view" >
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path="/signup"
                    element={
                     <>
                        {user ? (
                        <Navigate to="/" />
                        ) : ( <Col md={5}>
                            <SignupView />
                        </Col>
                        )}
                     </>
                    }
                />
                <Route 
                    path="/login"
                    element={
                     <>
                        {user ? (
                            <Navigate to="/" />
                        ) : ( <Col md={5}>
                            <LoginView onLoggedIn={(user, token) => {setUser(user); setToken(token); }}  /> 
                            </Col>
                        )}
                     </>
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path="/movies/:movieId"
                    element={
                     <>
                        {!user ? (
                        <Navigate to="/login" replace/>
                        ) : movies.length === 0 ? (
                            <>{showSpinner()}</>
                        ) : ( 
                            <Col md={9}>
                                <MovieView movies={movies} 
                                FavoriteMovies={user.FavoriteMovies} />
                            </Col>
                        )}
                     </>
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    element={
                     <>
                        <SearchBar onSearch={onSearch}/>
                        {!user ? (
                            <Navigate to="/login" replace/>
                        ) : loading ? (
                            <>{showSpinner()}</>
                            )
                         : userSearch && filteredMovies.length === 0 ? (
                            <Col className="mt-5">
                                Sorry, we could not find any match to your request
                            </Col>
                        ) : userSearch ? (
                         <>                            
                            {filteredMovies.map((movie) => (
                            <Col className="mb-5" key={movie._id} >
                                <MovieCard  movie={movie} user={user} updateUser={updateUser} />
                            </Col>
                            ))}
                        </>
                        ) 
                        : ( 
                        <>
                            {movies.map((movie) => (
                                <Col className="mb-5" key={movie._id}>
                                    <MovieCard movie={movie} user={user} updateUser={updateUser} />
                                </Col>
                            ))}
                        </>
                        )}
                     </>
              }
            />
            <Route
                path="/profile"
                element={
                    console.log(user) ||
                    <>
                    {user ? (
                        <Col className="mb-5" >
                            <ProfileView  user={user} setUser={setUser} movies={movies} updateUser={updateUser} key={user._id} />
                        </Col>
                    ) : (
                      <Navigate to="/login" />
                    )
                    }
                    </>
              }
            />
            </Routes>
        </Row>
</BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export { MainView };
```

[image]

So perhaps this might illustrate more my point: I have a parent component and then other child components within. How is it that the child does not follow along the 100% of the width of the view port?

It seems that if I were to change the component from the navigation out of the container it would use the full width.
Anyhow the way it is set up does not allow me that, since it will cause the app to crash. Main view is the component that will be called in my index.jsx file.

I solved it partially with this implementation:

```
.Navigation-bar{
    color: $color;
    background-color: $backgroundcolor;
    @media (min-width: 375px) {
        margin: 0px -12px;
    }
    @media (min-width:768px) {
        margin: 0px -36px;
    }
    @media (min-width:1024px) {
        margin: 0px -45px;
    }
    @media (min-width:1440px) {
        margin: 0px -73px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think  `#root { width: 90vw; }` may be the issue?

Comment: Thanks for poiting that out, but sadly no. I have tested while not ading anything to the root or even 100vw and I responds in a very strange manner.
If i can share a video it will most likely ilustrate better my bug.

Comment: You should share a snippet reproducting your issue instead. And remove all the code that is not relevant to your problem from your question.

Comment: So perhaps this might illustrate more my point: I have a parent component and then other child components within. How is it that the child does not follow along the 100% of the width of the view port?
function MainView() {
...}

Comment: I think I provided a better picture of what I am not really being able to solve with a proper solution (since manipulating the margins is against the standard)